# Entity framework AddOrUpdateOrDontBother with nesting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF code first with the following model:

```
public class Root
{
    public ChildA A { get; set; }
    public ChildB B { get; set; }
    public ChildC C { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose you have a controller

```
public class RecordController 
{
    ...

    public void Save(Root root)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

and your `Root` controller has received a model from client that contains the following changes: property `A` is totally new it has not yet been added to database and needs to be created, property `B` already exists in database and needs to be updated, property `C` not changed.

Action `Save` is not aware of what the property changes are, it just needs to update the `Record` properly and create missing or update existing sub models, it is also possible that some `Child` classes may also have their own nested changes, so I need a method that will somehow recurse through the model compare new model to existing one and will apply appropriate changes. So how do I do that?

Comment: +1 for the method name. Submitting an object graph is (still) a tedious job in EF. In Lerman & Miller's book _DbContext_ there is a proposed approach with manually coded self-tracking entities (of sorts). Not the silver bullet yet imo.

Comment: It can be useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with concatenating each of my model and ViewModel classes with `EntityState` property, so now when I change some property I set the `EntityState` to `changed` state, when I create one I set the property to state `Added`, initially models are initialised with `Unchanged` state, basically it looks something like the following:

```
[Table("City")]
[KnownType(typeof(Country))]
public class City
{
    public City()
    {
        Airports = new List<Airport>();
        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public Int32? CountryId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Range(-12, 13)]
    public Int32? TimeZone { get; set; }

    public Boolean? SummerTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public EntityState? EntityState { get; set; } // <----------- Here it is
}
```

Then on server I do the following

```
    [HttpPost, HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage SaveRecord(RecordViewModel record)
    {
        var model = Mapper.Map<Record>(record);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        db.Attach(model);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Here is implementation for Attach method:

```
    public void Attach(City entity)
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            Attach(entity.Country);

            AttachAndMarkAs(entity, entity.EntityState ?? EntityState.Added, instance => instance.Id);
        }
    }
    public void Attach(Country entity)
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            AttachAndMarkAs(entity, entity.EntityState ?? EntityState.Added, instance => instance.Id);
        }
    }
```

AttachAndMarkAs has the following implementation:

```
    public void AttachAndMarkAs<T>(T entity, EntityState state, Func<T, object> id) where T : class
    {
        var entry = Entry(entity);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            var set = Set<T>();

            T attachedEntity = set.Find(id(entity));

            if (attachedEntity != null)
            {
                var attachedEntry = Entry(attachedEntity);

                attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = state;
            }
        }
    }
```