# ASP.NET Core error : database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a problem and I tried to solve it a lot, which is when I want to modify the user data by the function `EditOrCreateInformation()` this error exception message appears:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

[Screenshot of the error is display here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck2vN.png)

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditOrCreateInformation(ApplicationUserVm model, ApplicationUser user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var olddata = context.Users.Where(a => a.Id == user.Id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        string oldfilename = olddata.PhotoUrl;

        if (model.Photo == null)
        {
            model.PhotoUrl = oldfilename;
        }

        if (oldfilename != null)
        {
            if (model.Photo != null && System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "PhotoFiles/PhotoProfile", oldfilename)))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "PhotoFiles/PhotoProfile", oldfilename));
                string PhysicalPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/wwwroot", "PhotoFiles/PhotoProfile/");
                // 2) Get File Name
                string FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(model.Photo.FileName);
                // 3) Merge Physical Path + File Name
                string FinalPath = Path.Combine(PhysicalPath, FileName);

                // 4) Save The File As Streams "Data Over Time"
                using(var stream = new FileStream(FinalPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.Photo.CopyTo(stream);
                }

                model.PhotoUrl = FileName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string PhysicalPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/wwwroot", "PhotoFiles/PhotoProfile/");
            // 2) Get File Name
            string FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetFileName(model.Photo.FileName);
            // 3) Merge Physical Path + File Name
            string FinalPath = Path.Combine(PhysicalPath, FileName);

            // 4) Save The File As Streams "Data Over Time"
            using(var stream = new FileStream(FinalPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                model.Photo.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            model.PhotoUrl = FileName;
        }

        var obj = mapper.Map < ApplicationUser > (model);
        applicationUser.Update(obj);

        toastNotification.AddSuccessToastMessage("Your Information Updated successfully");

        return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Profile", new
        {
            Area = "Identity"
        });
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Repository code:

```
public ApplicationUser Update(ApplicationUser obj)
{
    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == obj.Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

How can I fix this?

I will be very grateful to help me solve this problem.

Comment: Because the sql update where clause, which includes all PK and concurrency columns, did not impact any rows. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460686/unable-to-edit-db-entries-using-efcore-entitystate-modified-database-operatio

Comment: it's because the object you want to update is not the object that came from the database, so the first and the simplest way is to modify `oldData` instead the `model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here.

- using `AsNoTracking`
- using different `DbContext`

First, The `AsNoTracking` should be only used on read-only queries aka `SELECT`. If you need to `UPDATE` the same object, then you should select the object without using `AsNoTracking`.

Secondly, `Update` method you pass the modified `User` object to a different context that does not have the current object's change tracking history. So, when `SaveChanges` executed, it won't see any changes; because the object's changes were made in a different context.

so what you need to do is just remove `AsNoTracking` and replace these lines :

```
var obj = mapper.Map < ApplicationUser > (model);
applicationUser.Update(obj);
```

with this :

```
olddata.PhotoUrl = model.PhotoUrl;
context.Entry(olddata).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```