# Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I am add data in database working fine in local db but not working on live db and give me exception (Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s))
here is my code

```
var cal = new OutCall();
cal.PhoneNumberCalled = call.To;
cal.DateAdd = DateTime.Now;
cal.WorkerId = workerId;
            
_myDbContext.OutCalls.Add(cal);
                
_myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460686/unable-to-edit-db-entries-using-efcore-entitystate-modified-database-operatio

Comment: What is `cal` and how to you instantiate it?

Comment: cal is Class and name of OutCall and imagine call object is respone of api which contains data i want to store in db