# Entity Framework - save changes in detached entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework 7  in ASP.NET MVC app and try to save modified entity (from HTTP POST request) using **InsertOrUpdate pattern** [from this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
I also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record) post (3rd method).
This is my code:

```
private void insert_or_update<T>(T entity) where T : AbstractModel
{
    EntityState state;
    if (entity.ID == 0)
        state = EntityState.Added;
    else
        state = EntityState.Modified;

    dbcontext.Set<T>().Attach(entity);          //<- ERROR THERE
    dbcontext.Entry(entity).State = state;
    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I've got an error:

```
The instance of entity type 'Domain.Models.Section' cannot be tracked
because another instance of this type with the same key is already
being tracked.For new entities consider using an IIdentityGenerator
to generate unique key values.
```

I checked same questions there and I know, that repository shouldn't be added as an `Singleton`. This is my code from `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository, EFRepository>();
```

Is there any way to fix this and use only one query to database?

For example, this method using 2 queries (from [this question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record))

```
var original = db.Users.Find(updatedUser.UserId);
if (original != null)
{
   db.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedUser);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**UPD1:** EF7 has no member `CurrentValues` for `EntityEntry<T>`. So last method can't be used.

**UPD2:** `dbContext.Set<T>().Update()` gets same error.

Comment: It appears you have declared the `dbContext` outside of your function.  This is definitely not recommended.  Each function where database work is to occur should instantiate its own copy of the db context, do its work, and dispose of the context.  Long-lived db contexts do nothing but cause problems.

Comment: Could you show how are you calling repository method? Maybe it's something wrong there

Comment: it appears your context is pretty big. However, right now there are two hotfixes to your problem (but this problem is only one that occurs with ambient DbContexts): First, you can get your entity from your context, and copy the correct values there. I do not believe updating FK's right there is a good idea though. Second possibility could be an ambient ChangeTracker, this could further amplify your problems though.

Comment: I've got class `DatabaseContext` inherited inherited from `DbContext`.

Comment: *sorry, something going wrong with comment* 

I've got class `DatabaseContext` inherited inherited from `DbContext`. Then I have interface for repository `IRepository` and it's implementation `EFRepository` and It's get `DatabaseContext` in constructor. I inject the `EFRepository` using DI: `services.AddScoped<IRepository, EFRepository>();`
Controllers get `IRepository` in constructor. So, every time controller created, constructor of `DbContext` and  `EFRepository` call. So, **each  funtion works with own instance of dbcontext**, isn't is?