# EF6 insert or update for collection of entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert-update

I have next code :

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    var dbHistoryItems = context.Set<HistoryItem>();

    var historyItems = history as HistoryItem[] ?? history.ToArray();
    var historyItemIds = historyItems.Select(c => c.Id);

    var existingEntities = dbHistoryItems.Where(h => historyItemIds.Contains(h.Id));
    if (existingEntities.Any())
    {
        var newEntities = historyItems.Where(h => !existingEntities.Select(e => e.Id).Contains(h.Id));
        dbHistoryItems.AddRange(newEntities);   
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

where `history` is input parameter `List<HistoryInfo>`

When entity is new (entity with ID doesn't exist in Context) I add it to Context.
When entity is existing - I just want to save it (It can be modified).

Problem in this code is with Update. It doesn't update existing entities.

---

UPD:

Is there best way to insert or update collection of entities then in loop like:

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
   db.AddOrUpdate(item);
}
db.SaveChanges;
```

Comment: You're not changing any properties. Where does `history` come from and what updates do you expect to happen?

Comment: And no, _"history is input parameter List<HistoryInfo>"_ does not clarify that. Is this a detached entity, for example through an MVC form POST?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that EF does not detect changes within array elements. You can however force update. Check this [Entity Framework 5 Updating a Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record)

Comment: What does _"EF does not detect changes within array elements"_ mean? Also, if you think a question is answered elsewhere, flag as duplicate, please.

Comment: @CodeCaster For examle, sql type `varbinary` would be `byte[]` in EF. Changing some elements in array `byte[]` and calling `SaveChanges` will not detect that the array contents has been changed, and will not update.

Comment: That's right, you'll have to re-assign a a `byte[]` property on an entity or explicitly mark it as modified in order for the change tracker to pick up that change, but I don't really see how that relates to the question here.

Comment: @CodeCaster  maybe OP didn't put the related code to question. Code in the question is related to insert, while the question is about update.