# Getting Issue with generic T object in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I am Getting below error in Framework 4.5 WCF application.

[image]

Is there any missing file or else.
I don't getting exactly here.

Comment: Please show the definition of your class.

Comment: I have update method to Static still error at  Context.set  
I was try like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record

Answer (score 0):

Depends how your class does look like. Based on your screenshot you should change it to this

```
public void Update<T>(T obj, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] propertiesToUpdate)
{
}
```

Your version is only working, if the class would look like

```
public class YourClass<T>
{
   public void Update(T obj, ...
   {
   }
}
```

And here are the [basics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

**Edit**

Either you forgot to post it or you're doing it wrong.

If you're looking at the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) of `DbContext.Set<T>()`, then you'll see, that there is a constrain saying `where T : class`. (That's what I already mentioned in a comment.) That means, that your generic type has to meet the same requirement. Therefore you need to change your method to the following, since it need to be at least as specific as `DbContext.Set<T>()`.

```
public void Update<T>(T obj, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] propertiesToUpdate) where T : class
{
}
```

Last but not least, an advice. Deal with the basic of generics. It's pretty important. Once you have understood the whole thing, it can be very powerful in certain scenarios.

Comment: I have created method in class.. I have updated <T> but Context.Set<T>() is not working.. can I share teamviewer to you.

Comment: @AbhishekBhalani: Well since I don't know how `Context.Set<T>()` is definied, it's difficult to help. Might be that there is a constrain defined, which is not compatible with the other `T`. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: @AbhishekBhalani: How about sharing the code of `Update`. The tooltip on the picture is hidding some details. If possible, share also the code of `Context.Set`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record I was trying same.

Comment: I can show you via teamviewer if you have sometime.

Comment: I want to update entity model. but you know sometime it throw datetime error.   It throws "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated."

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
public void Update<T>(Task obj, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] propertiesToUpdate)
```

Comment: I was try like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record