# Entity Framework is not saving data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to save data to SQL Server from Entity Framework; this normally works and I don't know what I doing wrong here it's not throwing an error at all.

```
    try
    {
        tblPortalCustomerInfo _custInfo = new tblPortalCustomerInfo();
        _custInfo = _da.GetCustById(new Guid("397E4A4B-CD89-43DC-9E70-C19FC27EE6E4"));
        _custInfo.addressLine1 = tbaddress1.Text;
        _custInfo.addressLine2 = tbaddress2.Text;
        _custInfo.town = tbtown.Text;
        _custInfo.county = "test";
        _custInfo.postcode = tbpostCode.Text;
        _custInfo.email = tbEmail.Text;
        _custInfo.phone = tbDayPhone.Text;

        if(_custInfo.EntityState ==  System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _da.portalEntities.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.AddObject(_custInfo);
        }

        _da.SaveChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw;
   }
```

I have step through the code and no error is produced and it is getting attached ok here is my `GetCustById` function

```
// <returns></returns>
public tblPortalCustomerInfo GetCustById(Guid id)
{
        try
        {
            tblPortalCustomerInfo _customerInfo;

            _customerInfo = (from _custInfo in _dal.portalEntities.tblPortalCustomerInfoes    
                             where _custInfo.id == id 
                             select _custInfo).FirstOrDefault();

            //If the empNotes entity is null create a new one and attach it to the context.
            if (_customerInfo == null)
            { 
                _customerInfo = new tblPortalCustomerInfo();
                _dal.portalEntities.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.AddObject(_customerInfo);
            }

            return _customerInfo;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string inner = string.Empty;

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }
}
```

My portal entities is just off my context base

```
 public portalEntities1 _portalEntities;

 public portalEntities1 portalEntities
 {
     get
     {
            if (_portalEntities == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _portalEntities = new portalEntities1();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }

            return _portalEntities;
     }
}
```

Before you say am I doing a postback check yes I am here on my page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
            /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
            tblPortalCustomerInfo _myCustomerInfo = _da.GetCustById(new Guid("397E4A4B-CD89-43DC-9E70-C19FC27EE6E4"));

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                tbaddress1.Text = _myCustomerInfo.addressLine1;
                tbaddress2.Text = _myCustomerInfo.addressLine2;

                tbtown.Text = _myCustomerInfo.town;
                tbpostCode.Text = _myCustomerInfo.postcode;
                tbMobile.Text = _myCustomerInfo.mobile;
                tbEmail.Text = _myCustomerInfo.email;
                tbLandLine.Text = _myCustomerInfo.phone;
            }
}
```

My portal entities property which is in my context base

```
public portalEntities1 _portalEntities;

public portalEntities1 portalEntities
{
    get
    {
        if (_portalEntities == null)
        {
            try
            {
                _portalEntities = new portalEntities1();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        return _portalEntities;
    }
}
```

I get no error the information is just not saved to the db some reason anyone got any ideas

**Note 1**

Ok so I am using ef5 is this the right method to change a object state it seemed logical to me

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        tblPortalCustomerInfo _custInfo = new tblPortalCustomerInfo();
        _custInfo = _da.GetCustById(new Guid("397E4A4B-CD89-43DC-9E70-C19FC27EE6E4"));
        _custInfo.addressLine1 = tbaddress1.Text;
        _custInfo.addressLine2 = tbaddress2.Text;
        _custInfo.town = tbtown.Text;
        _custInfo.county = "test";
        _custInfo.postcode = tbpostCode.Text;
        _custInfo.email = tbEmail.Text;
        _custInfo.phone = tbDayPhone.Text;

        _da.portalEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_custInfo, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);  ----> is this correct for ef5

        _da.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I try the above method I am presented with

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.Entity.dll Additional information: The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'portalef.tblPortalCustomerInfo'.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a question with minimal code that is reproducing your issue. Also, empty `try`-`catch` blocks are not a good practice. What you can do here is go to the Debug-Exceptions and check the checkbox under **CLR Exceptions**. Then every thrown exception will be shown to you in the debug mode. Also you can implement step-by-step logging there to see where exactly does it crash. It’s difficult to say from the side perspective why that code doesn’t save entities currently.

Comment: @IvanYurchenko Hi sorry where is that option

Comment: Press `Ctrl+D,E` and there under **CLR Exceptions** check both ”thrown” and ”user-unhandled” options. This will help you to determine thrown but handled by `catch` block exceptions.

Comment: @IvanYurchenko i did that but still no error being produced its simply just not saving the record

Comment: Consider using Modified flag instead - as per [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov please see Note 1 in my edits above i treid above but its not working saving the object still no error im afriad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function called `GetCustById` you search for a customer with a specific id and if the customer doesn't exist you create it and then return it to the calling code.Either way the customer already exists in the database and calling [AddObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject(v=vs.110).aspx) will only create an entry in the database **if it does not yet exist**

Comment: yes but you note there while that is a good catch i am checking if the entity is detached or not

Comment: but your saying that i dont require it?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's detached according to the context.The fact is that the entry already exists in the database so calling AddObject() will not let you insert it.You need to find an alternative way of inserting this record, such as calling Add() but then you need to clear the primary key field otherwise you will get an error saying that an entry with this PK already exists

Comment: I removed that line of code so i did but its still not saving the record

Comment: Can you have look at my code additions its still not saving

Comment: Please try _dal.portalEntities.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.Add(_custInfo);

Comment: im using ef5 so only .addobject is in there

Comment: You mean EF4?Try clearing _custInfo.id and then call AddObject()

Comment: This was the answer in the end i had to upgrade to ef 6 though and used the entry modified command to set all my entitys to be added to context working now

Comment: Ok that's good that you got it working.You should use EF 5 or 6 it's much better than 4

Comment: Yeah I was using five actually but my own context did this and it worked right away