# Entity Framework - Updating entity's few columns only

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need some more understanding of how Entity Framework works. I have implemented code which is running ok and doing the job.

But I need to know that it is the good way or not.

I have a table with 8 columns, say

Table1

- Column1 (pk)
- Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8

Now when I click a button, I need to insert (if new) or update (for existing record) first 6 columns.

And on the same button click event, as part of the same process, I will call a stored procedure (with a parameter of primary key id, `Column1`) that will fetch these 6 columns values in the stored procedure itself and will do some calculations based on six column values and return two new values which I need to update in Column7, Column8.

So, process will be:

- New record: insert (six columns data), calculations (call stored procedure), update (last 2 column)
- Existing record: update (six columns data), calculations (call stored procedure), update(last 2 column)

Now, for insert, I use

```
_dbContext.Table1.Add(entity);
 _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

For existing record update (of first 6 columns), I use

```
//code - Entity property values are updated with new ones
_dbContext.Table1.Attach(entity);
_dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

For last update, Column7, Column8, I use

```
var entity = GetById(Id);

if (entity != null)
{
    entity.Column7 = value1;
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).Property(t => t.Column7).IsModified = true;
    entity.Column8 = value2;
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).Property(t => t.Column8).IsModified = true;

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am not sure why I need not to attach entity for last update. Is it due to I have called `GetById` method for same table just above that?

Without attaching entity how it updates columns? (if I attach entity it gives error saying already being tracked)

Also, I have to call `GetById` multiple times to get record for both updates (in existing record scenario). Any other solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use MapToModel method

here is example

```
//code - Entity property values are updated with new ones
var newEntity= new Entity
{
    Id = p.Id, // the Id you want to update
    Column1= ""  // put value for column/s that you need to update
};
newEntity.MapToModel(oldEntity);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I don't think you need to specify `IsModified` for each property if you fetch through the Context.

**EF Context will automatically track Entities unless you change the default behavior**

EF knows which entities are changed after loading from the database,hence it will be only updated.

*Assuming `GetById` is fetching the data from data-store.*

```
var entity = GetById(Id);

if (entity != null)
{
    entity.Column7 = value1;
    entity.Column8 = value2;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

[Detect Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556205(v=vs.113).aspx)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record?rq=1)