# AJAX Call to Update table goes Null - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to update my table using Ajax Call through this code

```
 var customer = {};
        customer.CustomerId = row.find(".CustomerId").find("span").html();
        customer.Nome = row.find(".Nome").find("span").html();
        customer.Tipo = row.find(".Tipo").find("span").html();
        customer.NCM = row.find(".NCM").find("span").html();
        customer.Contabil = row.find(".Contabil").find("span").html();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
            data: '{customer:' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    });
```

But when I click to update the value it returns a System.NullReferenceException, I can't see where I'm doing wrong.

Here's my Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        using (CustomersEntities entities = new CustomersEntities())
        {
            Customer updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.Customers
                                        where c.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId
                                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
            updatedCustomer.Nome = customer.Nome;
            updatedCustomer.Tipo = customer.Tipo;
            updatedCustomer.NCM = customer.NCM;
            updatedCustomer.Contabil = customer.Contabil;
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: You aren't sending valid JSON. `data: { customer }` should do it. Alternatively: `{ customer: customer }` or `JSON.stringify({ customer: customer })` (as a rule of thumb: *never* compose JSON by hand, and *never* use stringify unless you a) know what it does b) are absolutely positive you have to use it)

Comment: @ChrisG Well it worked partially, No more Exception, but now the data isn't updating in my DB.

Comment: Looking at the jQuery docs, it looks like you might have to always stringify after all; jQuery apparently turns the data into a query string otherwise. Still, you should log `entities` on the server-side to narrow down the problem.

Comment: The `contentType: application/json` probably is the culprit here. I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mF43mr) to demonstrate passing table contents through AJAX and getting results, just using `data: customer` and remove the `contentType` option from AJAX callback.

Answer (score 1):

System.NullReferenceException revealed the value updatedCustomer or customer is null.You need check which is null.

And when  you want to update a  enity in EF,you need add code like :

```
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Howerver,Why you need Query A Entity befor update?I guess you want to do this:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
      using (CustomersEntities entities = new CustomersEntities())
       {
          entities.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
          entities.SaveChanges();
       }
       return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This AJAX callback below actually passed JSON string containing JSON object, which is wrong and causing `customer` contains null value which throwing `NullReferenceException` (it is strongly advised to put null check before using EF entity context):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
    data: '{customer:' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}', // this is wrong 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Instead of passing JSON string like that, just use `data: JSON.stringify(customer)` or simply passing entire object directly with `data: customer` and remove `contentType` setting:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
    data: customer, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Regarding second issue which selected data from table query is not updated, it depends on auto-tracking setting from EF. If auto-tracking is disabled, you need to set `EntityState.Modified` before using `SaveChanges()`:

```
if (customer != null)
{
    using (CustomersEntities entities = new CustomersEntities())
    {
        Customer updatedCustomer = (from c in entities.Customers
                                    where c.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId
                                    select c).FirstOrDefault();

        updatedCustomer.Nome = customer.Nome;
        updatedCustomer.Tipo = customer.Tipo;
        updatedCustomer.NCM = customer.NCM;
        updatedCustomer.Contabil = customer.Contabil;

        // if EF auto-tracking is disabled, this line is mandatory 
        entities.Entry(updatedCustomer).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1) You can see all methods to update existing data with EF in [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record).

2) [This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mF43mr) contains sample to make AJAX request from a table contents.

Comment: It continues giving me NullReference Exception, what I noticed is that it doesn't matter which field I update, the exception only happens in this line  updatedCustomer.Nome = customer.Nome;