# How to cascade updates in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am trying to update a table and its related entities but the child entities are not updating. I don't know if the child entities should update automatically, or if I need to manually update them. Or I don't know if my EF configuration or database configuration are incorrect.

My tables are Template and TemplateFields. A template can have many templateFields but a templateField can only have one parent template. Here is my [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCfGG.png).

And here are my table configurations in EF:

```
public class TemplateConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Template>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Template> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.HasMany(template => template.TemplateFields)
            .WithOne(field => field.ParentTemplate)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

public class TemplateFieldConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<TemplateField>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TemplateField> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.HasOne(field => field.ParentTemplate)
            .WithMany(template => template.TemplateFields);
    }
}
```

Here's the Template model:

```
[Table("Template")]
public class Template : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TemplateField> TemplateFields { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the TemplateField model:

```
[Table("TemplateField")]
public class TemplateField : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual Template ParentTemplate { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DataType DataType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual bool IsSharedAcrossLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Template update method:

```
    public virtual async Task<Template> EditAsync(Template template)
    {
        var originalItem = await _dbContext.Template.FindAsync(template.Id);
        _dbContext.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(template);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        var newTemplate = await _dbContext.Template.FindAsync(template.Id);

        return newTemplate;
    }
```

Here is some example JSON payload I've been testing with to add a template and associated fields:

```
{
    "name": "New Template",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "Title",
            "dataType": "text",
            "isSharedAcrossLanguages": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Content",
            "dataType": "image",
            "isSharedAcrossLanguages": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Header",
            "dataType": "text",
            "isSharedAcrossLanguages": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And last of all here is the payload for updating a template and its fields (with example Guids):

```
{
    "id": "32e2ff27-24e6-49d4-bea7-08d924513aa3",
    "name": "Edited Template",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": "80072a3a-c717-4ab0-53ef-08d924513aae",
            "name": "Edited Title",
            "dataType": "text",
            "isSharedAcrossLanguages": false
        },
        {
            "id": "3865f8b1-0f3c-4edc-53f0-08d924513aae",
            "name": "Content",
            "dataType": "image",
            "isSharedAcrossLanguages": true
        },
        {
            "id": "57b5b7af-d265-4244-53f1-08d924513aae",
            "name": "Header",
            "dataType": "text",
            "isSharedAcrossLanguages": false
        }
    ]
}
```

What's confusing to me is the standard EF method `AddAsync()` will cascade adding child templateFields automatically, which tells me cascading updates should be possible. What I'm thinking is that '_dbContext.Entry(originalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(template);' only gets values that have changed and since my Template table does not contain a foreign key column pointing to the TemplateField table, EF can't recognize it as a changed value.

Is that a correct assumption? If so, is there a way to get cascading updates to work?

Comment: When you load the template with `FindAsync()` try to call `Include(t => t.TemplateFields)` on the `DbSet` first. This should ensure they are actually loaded into memory. You might have to use  `Single()` or `First()` instead of `FindAsync()` though.

Comment: I will try that out, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `CurrentValues` only includes properties that correspond to columns in the database. Which I think makes sense after thinking about it. When EF populates the model from the database it doesn't go deep enough to recognize the relationship with the `TemplateFields` model.

The `TemplateFields` property in my model is a reference/navigation property and does not have or need a corresponding column in the database. So because of this, EF doesn't recognize that the TemplateFields have any changes.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record) SO post on the different ways of updating and method 1 will work just fine for my purposes. Just updating each field individually as follows:

```
var original = db.Users.Find(updatedUser.UserId);

if (original != null)
{
    original.BusinessEntityId = updatedUser.BusinessEntityId;
    original.Email = updatedUser.Email;
    original.EmployeeId = updatedUser.EmployeeId;
    original.Forename = updatedUser.Forename;
    original.Surname = updatedUser.Surname;
    original.Telephone = updatedUser.Telephone;
    original.Title = updatedUser.Title;
    original.Fax = updatedUser.Fax;
    original.ASPNetUserId = updatedUser.ASPNetUserId;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```