# Modify entity using Action in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to have method to update only specified properties in my entity. So I created method as below:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(string uri, Action<Models.RequestObject> modify, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    Entities.RequestObject entity = _dbContext.RequestObjects.Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Uri == uri)
        ?? await _dbContext.RequestObjects.AsTracking().Where(p => p.Uri == uri).SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (entity != default)
    {
        Models.RequestObject entityAsModel = entity.ToModel();
        modify.Invoke(entityAsModel);

        entity = entityAsModel.ToEntity();
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

But this method, due to project architecture, accepts `Models.RequestObject` as `Action` generic type, but I need to modify `Entities.RequestObject`. The code I provided doesn't work. Any ideas why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is not working, is because you are not updating the entity that is being tracked by the entity framework.

- You first get the entity
- Then you map it to a model
- Then you update the model
- Then you map the model back to an entity and reassign it to the entity variable

So now you have 2 entity objects in memory 1 that you fetched from the entity framework and one which you reated by calling `.ToEntity()`

If you change the code to modify the entity that you got back from the entity framework e.g.

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(string uri, Action<Models.RequestObject> modify, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    Entities.RequestObject entity = _dbContext.RequestObjects.Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Uri == uri)
        ?? await _dbContext.RequestObjects.AsTracking().Where(p => p.Uri == uri).SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (entity != default)
    {
        Models.RequestObject entityAsModel = entity.ToModel();
        modify.Invoke(entityAsModel);

        entity.prop1 = entityAsModel.prop1;
        entity.prop2 = entityAsModel.prop2;

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then it will properly update the entity in the database.

Comment: Hm, but any ideas how to avoid manually setting up properties?

Comment: @Szyszka947 What I’ve done in the past is use `AutoMapper` `mapper.Map(source,destination)` but honestly there are a lot of different ways to avoid manually setting the properties, it can probably be a question on it’s own on stack overflow. It might’ve already been asked before.

Comment: @Szyszka947 Here are some alternative ways for updating which might you might consider taking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record?rq=1